# The indefinite article "a" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is it correct to write: *Small change makes a big difference*  or do I need an indefinite article *a* at the beginning of the sentence? Why?

Comment: This has nothing to do with it being at the beginning of the sentence. Literally nothing at all.

Answer (score 15):

I would use one of the following two sentences:

> ***A*** small change ***makes*** a big difference.
>   Small ***changes make*** a big difference.

In other words, with an "a" I'd frame it in the singular—because you're talking about a single small change; otherwise, in the plural—because you're talking about small changes in general.

Here, I'm thinking of [*change*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/change) meaning "the act, process, or result of changing."

---

The only way I can make sense of "small change" *without* an "a" being put in the singular is when I think of *change* meaning "coins especially of low denominations · a pocketful of *change*."

With *that* meaning, then it makes sense to say:

> ***Small change makes*** a big difference (when it comes to tipping your server).

And here, **small change** is being treated as a collective singular, in the same way that an uncountable noun would be.

I believe this answer (aside from the specific final example) will apply to any other *countable* noun. For instance, you would treat **smart idea** in the same manner.

However, it would not apply to uncountable nouns. **Water**, always in the singular without something additional (like *body of*), would never take "a" front of it.

---

As one comment validly pointed out, you can order "a water" (or "a coffee") at a restaurant. But, in that case, I would argue that you are using an uncountable noun *as if* it were countable. (And, in terms of meaning, assuming that the missing "bottle of," "glass of," or "cup of" is understood.)

Comment: It's odd that the original sentence could actually pass if it excluded _small_. Great explanation.

Comment: Yeah, this covers the entire question completely (incl. 'small change' referring to money), to the point where there's nothing left for others to write. The only improvement I could suggest is the obiter dictum on 'water' is too strong. '*A* water' certainly exists in certain contexts, particularly ordering at restaurants; many uncountable words can be countable when used to discuss *one instance* or *one kind* of the stuff.

Comment: I believe the original meaning of the phrase is in reference to coins. It might be said in a conversation like so: Bob - "Hey! There's a penny!" Tom - "Meh, not worth it to pick up such small change." Bob - "*Small change makes a big difference.*" (Bob picks up the penny).

Comment: I would argue that "Small change makes a big difference" in the sense of the act of changing is still valid, in the same sense that you could say "Change is coming", rather than "A change is coming"

Comment: @Mayube But you wouldn't say *small change is coming*. By extension, I think that your sense of *small change makes a big difference* is at least highly unusual ...

Comment: @lly Good point! I have updated my answer to mention that.

Comment: @Mayube If you strongly believe that, you could write up a separate answer, but it would get downvoted because it's wrong. Like Mr Bassford already said, 'change' can be an uncountable abstract idea or countable instance of change; *changes* can be small but there is no abstract idea of 'small change', only a mass noun for 'too many small coins to bother counting'.